# A Mysql syntax error. How can I solve this?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I have a query that I can run in phpmyadmin without any erros and the records that it returns are true.

```
LOCK TABLE menu WRITE;
                                SELECT @myLeft := lft FROM menu
                                WHERE name = 'myName';
                                UPDATE menu SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;
                                UPDATE menu SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;
                                INSERT INTO menu(name, lft, rgt);
                                VALUES('new name', @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2);
                                UNLOCK TABLES";
```

But when I want to run into my php code, there are some errors:
Is the synax true??

```
<?php 
    $name = "FRS";
    $parent = "QQQQQQQQ";

    $query = $this->db->query("LOCK TABLE menu WRITE
                                SELECT @myLeft := lft FROM menu
                                WHERE name = ?
                                UPDATE menu SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft
                                UPDATE menu SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft
                                INSERT INTO menu(name, lft, rgt)
                                VALUES(?, @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2)
                                UNLOCK TABLES",
                                array($name, $parent));
if($query)
        return true;
?>
```

I also use it with semicolon like the query that I run in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Is it a MySQL error or PHP error? and as @Rahul mentioned what is the exact error?

Comment: PHP will not execute multiple queries out of the box. You need to execute each one seperatly.

Comment: @Rahul You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT ....

Comment: @h2ooooooo Are you sure???

Comment: That's cause you are missing a `;` after the first `LOCK TABLE menu WRITE` statement and for rest of the queries as well. Moreover, that's not a recommended way.

Comment: @Rahul I've tested it. But again there is the same error. Why it works in phpmyadmin but not in php codes!?

Comment: Consider going through a procedure instead. Probably, it's not allowed in PHP as h20000 said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about PHP but you should consider running the SQL code as procedure like below. Also, to point out there is a extra semicolon `;` in your insert query ans pointed below

```
INSERT INTO menu(name, lft, rgt);
                                <--Here
VALUES('new name', @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2);
```

Procedure body

```
delimiter $$
create procedure sp_dowork
as
begin

LOCK TABLE menu WRITE;
SELECT @myLeft := lft FROM menu WHERE name = 'myName';

UPDATE menu SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;

UPDATE menu SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;

INSERT INTO menu(name, lft, rgt)
VALUES('new name', @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2);

UNLOCK TABLES;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

Then call your procedure in you application code accordingly

Comment: Is this a php code?? what do you mean by Procedure?

Comment: @vahidnajafi, NO this is SQL code. Procedure is used to run a group of statement together instead of running then as blob of query separated by `;`. See more on MySQL documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: but I don't have any problem in SQL code. It's completely true. The problem is in php.